# Non-classical logics vs substructural logics

Tags: logic

Could someone please explain in simple words the difference between a non-classical logic and a substructural logic? (For instance, are substructural logics a subset of non-classical logics?)
Actually, I'm afraid I don't completely get what it takes for a specific logic to be called "classical" in the first place.

Comment: [Classical Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/).

Comment: [Non-classical logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_logic) is more vague : many-valued, intuitionistic, modal, paraconsistent, etc.

Comment: [Substructural logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_logic) "is a logic lacking one of the usual structural rules (e.g. of classical and intuitionistic logic), such as weakening, contraction, exchange or associativity." In this sense, is non-classical, but at the same time is in contraposition to both classical and intuitionistic.

Comment: As with most broad categorizations, “classical” means different things to different people. (Are classical modal logics classical logics?) Best to focus on what things are rather than what they’re called.